# How to redirect or load new PHP page from PHP using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was trying to load new php page from one the PHP page using Jquery.

```
window.location = 'admin-editcp.php'; //no success
$(location).attr('href','admin-editcp.php'); // no success
```

Checked my browser JS is also enabled. I tried it with Mozila, IE and Chrome.

Then i manage site in dreamweaver and I checked it there via live preview and when i clicked in click event, it loads properly.

But not in the above two methods with 3 browser.

I am confuse that what is missing here????

What I have tried:

Comment: `location.href='admin-editcp.php';`?

Comment: hi, I tried all methods but no success. Please read my query again as I have mentioned that all ways work with Dreamweaver but none of the way work when i try with browser

Comment: do you have JQ library in your live website ? this works `$("button").click(function(){
location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
})`

Comment: I think you are confusing client and server side functionality....php cannot do anything on the client side except create content.  PHP executes only on the server, if you want to do something with the client then its entirely down to JavaScript.

Comment: hi @SPlatten, you are true. but it does not mean that we cannot load server page with client side scripting...

Comment: @Mihai T, I tested as the direction given by you and it works. I got what is the issue.. I was using $("nav ul li a").click(function(){
........
}
and calling to corresponding function....
Now I only need to replace nav ul li a with proper event. Actually, I want when I click nav->ul->a then the corresponing should executes

Comment: @VPartapSinghSalathia, so why not just use location.reload(); on the client side?  Or to redirect, location.href = 'newpage';

Comment: As,  I am trying to use all the ways but its not triggering because my click event is not correct..
$('ul.nav li').on("click", function(){
     alert("hi");
     location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"; 
     //var NavId = this.id;
     
    //fxnNavClicked(NavId);
     
  });
I am not able to find the correct way to resolve the issue. 

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav temp-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
when i click on a then new page reload

Comment: This is the code
 $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
     alert("hi");
     location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"; 
     //var NavId = this.id;
     
    //fxnNavClicked(NavId);
     
  });
Alert is displaying Hi. but the page does not loads

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'location.href' for this

```
location.href = "admin-editcp.php";
```

Comment: @RamRaider replied for the same and i replied that no success

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
jQuery('#id').on('click', function(){
   // Perform your action on click here, like redirecting to a sign-up url
    window.location='https://www.requiredpageurl.php';

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're allmost correct. It should be:

```
window.location.href = "admin-editcp.php";
```